# Remove persistent zombie process from the command line

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, process, adb

I run adb regularly and sometimes it stops working.

```
$ ps aux

user1  4175  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   Feb27   0:03 [adb] <defunct>
```

This zombie process stops adb working and I can't get adb working again without restarting the computer.

I have tried sending

```
kill 4175
kill -9 4175 
kill-17 4175
```

but nothing 'reaps' the zombie process.

How can I get adb working again without restarting the computer?

Also, I'm using:

```
Linux user1 2.6.32-38-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:12:07 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Using the latest version of ADB (1.0.29) reduced the frequency of the zombie process occurring.

Comment: With the latest version ($ adb version: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29), it still tends to end up defunct.

Comment: Any updates on this?  Remember, killing the parent process isn't a viable option, since it's init.

Comment: no updates, we haven't had it occur since we updated the ADB version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only `kill` command that reaps the zombie process is the one that kills its parent, since it will then reparent to `init` which will then proceed to reap it.

Not really possible when it's a kernel thread though...

Comment: @Neeraj: ... Kill the parent.

Comment: Which isn't really a good idea if the parent is init. which happens in my case everytime when adb becomes defunct. I don't care about a defunct adb floating around. But it prevents running adb until you reboot.

Comment: @aseq: init should be reaping the zombie. Are you saying that it isn't?

Comment: It is not, the adb process is just staying there in defunct mode with parent process being init. I have found no way to get adb working again unless I reboot, which is unfortunate, since I like to save my set up and use hibernate. By the way in my case after adb became unusable I tried to kill -1 it and then it became defunct. It was already owned by init.

Comment: As I said above, using the latest version of ADB seemed to work for me. I guess the next step would be debugging ADB itself. I think the source is in c if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Stu adb shouldn't need to be debugged.  Even if it terminates improperly, the operating system should be able to recover.  As a side note, I'm having this problem with the latest version of adb.

Comment: @Zenexer - true, but if the OS isn't dealing with a certain condition correctly, it's probably easier to debug an app than an OS (depending on your skill set). Potentially the app can be modified to exit in a manner that the OS can cope with or address the condition and self recover. I haven't seen a zombie process in the last 3 months using ADB 1.0.29, so I haven't looked into the problem any further.

Comment: I think that it might have had something to do with USB resources being left open.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Correct, init is not reaping the zombie process, possibly because USB resources remain open.

Answer (score 0):

I also see this often. It is caused by a thread being stuck in kernel mode when the program exits. You can see this with ps mx:

```
# ps mx
  17188 ?        -      1:49 [adb] <defunct>
      - -        Zl     0:01 -
      - -        Dl     1:46 -
```

The "D" state of the second thread indicates the thread is in kernel mode, and cannot be killed. You can read more about this here:

http://ntucsie2007.wikidot.com/linux-defunct-zombie-processes

Unfortunately, I think adb will have to be changed to exit cleanly.